# Installing Qgis2 on openSUSE 13.1

Tags: installation, qgis-2

I need to install Qgis2 on my openSUSE 13.1 box but its standard repo ([Application:Geo](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?project=Application%3aGeo&package=qgis2)) on software.opensuse.org reports a build error. Has anyone already found a way to get it working?

martin

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 2.0 is not provided for openSUSE 13.1 yet. See this [list of available versions and repos](http://software.opensuse.org/package/qgis2) for QGIS 2.0. I believe we will need to wait up to 1 month before QGIS will be available for the newest version of the openSUSE.

The only option you have for now is to build QGIS and all needed dependencies (GDAL, etc.) from source.